# Filter columns that contain more than a single value and null in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I want to filter the columns that contain more than a single unique value. But my dataframe has null values and that makes the column look like it has more than 1 value. For example for `col1` we should only have 2 unique values, 3 unique values for `col2` and 1 unique value for `col3`. So I only want the columns  1 and 2 as they contain more than 1 unique value.

```r
dat <- data.frame(col1 = I(list(NULL,"apple","orange")), col2 = c("soccer", "tennis", "football"), col3 = I(list("sand", NULL, NULL)))

Filter(function(x)(length(unique(x))>1), dat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are `list`.  Use `unlist` to create a `vector` before calling the `unique` and `length`

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(na.omit(unlist(x)))) > 1, dat)
```

-output

```
    col1     col2
1          soccer
2  apple   tennis
3 orange football
```

---

Or use `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    select(where(~ n_distinct(unlist(.), na.rm = TRUE) > 1))
    col1     col2
1          soccer
2  apple   tennis
3 orange football
```

Comment: What if null values are denoted with <NA>?

Comment: @moli THen you may need to wrap the `unlist` with `na.omit(unlist)` before the `unique`

Comment: @moli updated the post with one more option